# Brute-forcing the theory of everything

Tags: computational-physics, theory-of-everything

If brute force doesn't work, you're probably just not using enough of it. That's especially true for guessing combinations of stuff, like characters in a password. Assuming some combination of computer instructions can represent the mathematics of TOE (and that we'll have a supercomputer powerful enough to do this), it should be possible to write a program that in a brute force fashion goes through all the possible combinations of computer instructions (with a reasonable length limit) and for each combination checks if the randomized program can accurately predict the future of some systems that we already understand very well so we know their future with high precision.

This is a 2 part question:

1. Are there any problems such a program could run into? Perhaps verifying the correctness of the randomized theories would be difficult since we can get many very similar theories that would yield very similar results, too similar for us to experimentally detect the difference?
2. Was there ever any attempt to brute-force old theories (such as neutonian mechanics or even simpler stuff) as a proof of concept?

Comment: We can't even brute-force long passwords with reasonable effort. A password certainly is much less complex than a coherent physical theory. What makes you think brute-forcing an entire physical theory would even be remotely feasible? How are you setting up the "space of theories" this brute-forcing is supposed to explore?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Obviously the computers we have nowadays aren't powerful enough for this but I'm talking about the general concept of brute forcing a theory, not constrained by today's computation speed.

Comment: There doesn't have to be a "space of theories", with enough brute force you could randomize programs that do pretty much anything including programs that take your defined initial states as an input and return an output describing the prediction Most randomized programs won't do it, but some will because you go through all the possibilities. Though alternatively you could do something like a program that instead of purely randomizing computer instructions will randomize definitions of functions and objects, and equations that use them.

Comment: How will you *know* your brute-force-proposed outcome is right or wrong? How will you know the Odyssey your program produced *but for a single chapter* is not the original version? Hell, TOEs are on the decline *precisely* because there are precious few ways to *know they are right or wrong* at this point in time.

Comment: @CosmasZachos yeah that's the expected problem I mentioned in my question, I was just wondering if there are any other problems this approach could run into.

Comment: I wish you would not use "brute force" as a verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don’t have enough time to do this using classical computers, even if every Planck volume in the observable universe contained a computer executing programs at one instruction per Planck time since the Big Bang.

Let’s consider Java as a typical language. Java has about 200 opcodes for its virtual mechine. Suppose a simulation program requires 1000 instructions. (It probably needs more like millions.) Then you have to explore $200^{1000}$ or about $1.1\times10^{2301}$ programs. Good luck with that!

Brute force is not going to find a Theory of Everything that looks like, say, quantum field theory, general relativity, or string theory. I would be surprised if it could find a Theory of Anything.

Obviously the combinatorics are the reason why no theories like our current theories have been discovered using this approach. However, I believe Stephen Wolfram has advocated a systematic exploration of finite automata in hopes of finding interesting physics. The idea as I understand it is that physics might be vastly simpler at tiny scales than our current theories are, and the “program” the universe is executing might be quite short, and the number of “opcodes” quite small.

I will let someone knowledable about quantum computers comment on their capabilities regarding brute-force exploration of all possible programs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So basically getting enough brute force using classical computers is not feasible, at least as long as we can't narrow the search down enough.

Comment: Yes, that’s my claim.

Comment: "Java as a typical language" *shudders*.

Comment: Even doing brute force searches in a 16×16 grid in the simple universe of Conway's Game of Life is hard work, as discussed [here](http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Catagolue). Lots of interesting stuff has been discovered in Life via restricted random searches, eg colliding small numbers of gliders into various stable patterns, but even in those cases there's still plenty of unexplored interesting configurations. New 3 glider collisions are still being found.